# Terminal do PhpStorm não reconhece php do xampp

Tags: laravel, terminal, phpstorm

Alguém sabe porque o terminal do PhpStorm não reconhece php do xampp?

Porque no terminal do Windows funciona normal

o composer, o php usado com laravel, mas no terminal do phpstorm não funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri como resolver.

Caso alguém precise, fiz assim:

Creio que a sequência era para ser assim:

1. Instalar o XAMPP;
2. Instalar o PHPStorm;

Eu fiz ao contrário e por isso não funcionava.

Removi o PhpStorm e fiz essa sequencia assim e funcionou.